# Why do frameworks and git hub ask you to use Terminal?

Tags: javascript, macos, frameworks, terminal

I'm a newbie and that's ok.

But when I use tutorials, they always tell me to go straight to my terminal and install documents from there in which I have no clue what the next step is and no idea why I have to do it. Is it essential that I install frameworks through terminal or can I just work without it?

ex. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/real-time-messaging-for-meteor-with-meteor-streams/

"Let’s create a very simple, browser console based chat application with Meteor Streams. We’ll first create a new Meteor application:"

```
meteor create hello-stream
```

I understand this is may not be very challenging, but I don't have a clear answer when I try and simply google it. Anything would help, thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, the terminal is an essential tool. You'll have to learn it eventually one way or another. I'd start with this good [introduction to unix commands](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Teaching/Unix/)

Comment: I may be from the spoiled GUI generation, but even then I can see that terminals are way more simplistic than any GUI tool (even more when you're following instructions).

Comment: Isn't it easier to just use a text editor? Or is that completely different?

Comment: This question is better suited for http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

Being a newbie is ok.

The terminal is the go to because writing programs, tools, and scripts with a couple lines of bash or python is, well, a couple of lines versus an entire gui and all the lines of code to go with it.

```
meteor create hello-stream
```

That's telling you to run the program called `meteor` with the supplied arguments (`create hello-stream`).

If you haven't installed meteor, do that next. From their [website](http://www.meteor.com/examples/leaderboard), open your terminal and type/paste:

```
curl https://install.meteor.com | sh
```

That downloads a file from the URL and pipes (`|`) it to the `sh` command. The file it downloads is a shell script that takes care of setup/installation. Now go back and try the meteor command again.

## More reading

You might try and find a terminal tutorial. This is the first one I found:

http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Teaching/Unix/

Answer (score 1):

Answer from someone who only recently (as in: within the last year) got into using the Terminal more and more frequently:

It's generally a good idea to get used to using the Terminal for code-related things as you can pretty much use it platform-independently (meaning you can use the same commands on Mac, Linux, Windows,...) and because it makes you understand better what you're actually doing.

Once you've got the hang of it, it can make navigating your system as well as making changes to it easier. Hidden files, for example (like .gitignore files, or files in your .ssh directory, or your .bash_profile), can be viewed, opened and edited easily from the Terminal whereas you have to take multiple, complicated steps (or install other software) to view them from your Finder.

With the help of package managers (like Homebrew), which are also operated from the Terminal, you can also install software that isn't otherwise available for Mac.